# C programs are not compiled in my Kali Linux

Tags: c, gcc

My *sample.c* program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(“Hello, World!\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

When I want compile it, I see this error (as root):

```
cd ~/Desktop
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc sample.c -o file.exe
```

Output:

```
sample.c: In function ‘main’:
sample.c:5:2: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
sample.c:5:2: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
sample.c:5:2: error: stray ‘\234’ in program
sample.c:5:12: error: ‘Hello’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sample.c:5:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sample.c:5:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘World’
sample.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\’ in program

sample.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
sample.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
sample.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\235’ in program
```

I can't compile any C format file. How can I fix it?

Note: It cross compiles to Windows, thus *"file.exe"*.

Comment: Its those pesky smart quotes `“Hello World!\n”`.  Use normal quotes`"`.

Comment: It is certainly a duplicate - just cannot find it fast.  Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/19198332/2410359 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334454/how-do-i-make-this-simple-shellcode-c-program-compile-from-terminal/11334478#11334478

Comment: thanks bro I changed it but still it isn't compiled : root@Kali:~/Desktop# gcc sample.c -o file
/tmp/cciJWsOr.o: In function `main':
sample.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Hmmm "undefined reference to print" -- should not that be `printf`  (missing f)?  Suggest changing to a program editor.

Comment: Direct analysis: 342 200 234 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9C (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201C ([LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). And 342 200 235 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9D (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201D ([RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). They can be searched for (and replaced) with the regular expression `\x{201C}|\x{201D}` in any modern text editor or IDE (different notation in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u201C|\u201D`).

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: It is the wrong close reason. It should be closed as a duplicate of a canonical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your editor. ***”*** (**quotation marks**) and *"* is different and ***”*** is causing the error.
Try with **"**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(“Hello, World!\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

Try another code editor.

Comment: Re *"This is due to your editor."*: Unlikely. It is much more likely it is caused by copying code from a web page or PDF document.